# Flyway give ORA-00900 when I try to EXEC stored procedure from package

Tags: oracle, flyway

I have some oracle sql scripts, which run perfectly from SQLDeveloper or from SQLPlus. Now I want to implement Flyway tool to control DB migration. But when I try to execute following string

```
EXEC USERNAME.PA_SECURITY.SP_TBL_PLC_ADD('V_NAME', USERNAME.PA_SECURITY.POLICY_NAME);
```

I got an error ORA-00900 : invalid SQL statement.
From flyway documentation I don't see any restrictions for using SP. But I don't understand, what is wrong with my SQL. It's working with other tools.

Comment: `exec` is a SQL\*Plus (or SQL Developer) command, it's not a regular [SQL command](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm). You can't execute it through JDBC (which I think Flyway is using). You need to wrap that into an anonymous PL/SQL block (or convince Flyway to use a `CallableStatement`)

Comment: Thanks! It's works

Answer (score 1):

As a_horse_with_no_name explain I need to use following syntax

```
BEGIN 
   USERNAME.PA_SECURITY.SP_TBL_PLC_ADD('V_NAME', USERNAME.PA_SECURITY.POLICY_NAME);
END;
```

i.e. remove EXEC statement and add "BEGIN ... END;" frame.